# R xml2 using XPath3.0

Tags: r, xpath, libxml2, xml2

I would just like to know if `xml2` R package will eventually use XPath3.0 instead of XPath1.0? I know the package is built on top of the `libxml2` C library, which still use Xpath1.0, but I can't find if there is a planned update soon to go to XPath3.0.

Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/why-doesnt-libxml2-support-xpath-2-0/205581 (though apparently that doesn't make it a duplicate because it's on a different forum...)

Comment: Your link is dead @MichaelKay !

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: @MichaelKay The link only works for users that have the privilege to view deleted questions. This requires 10K reputation on  softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the general public can't answer questions regarding the future directions of OSS projects.

Comment: That said, I contribute to libxml2, and I think it's highly unlikely that XPath 3.0 support will be added in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Very irritating when you go to the trouble of giving a detailed and accurate answer to a question and then someone deletes the question - especially when the same question then gets asked again.